# Python throws exception when we try to get a list of files inside directory on Solaris

Tags: python

When we try to execute listdir on Solaris, python throws exception because lost+found, which is system folder inside directory where we run listdir, cannot be accessed.

```
instanceDirs = listdir(baseDir)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/some path/lost+found'
```

How we can bypass this problem and return a list of all files and directories to which we have permissions?

Comment: Are you doing this recursively or just one level deep?  What is `baseDir` in this example, is it `/some path/`?

Comment: right, baseDir is some path

Comment: What are the permissions like?  Because I tried reproducing this on my system by making a directory within a directory and doing `chmod 0` on that child directory, and `listdir(parent)` still worked.

Comment: For lost +found folder they looks like this:


drwx------   2 root     root        8192 Jan 17 05:32 lost+found

Comment: Can you run your program like `strace -f myscript.py |& grep 'lost+found'` and add the output to your question?

Comment: it complains about
ERROR: unable to open /dev/log
and also & fails, but I removed it. trying to find why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: with **try except pass** it ignores exception and always returns full list of files and dirs.